# Postgres Corruption Error: Duplicate rows with the same primary key

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, corrupt

I recently hit a Postgres error (my DB corrupted), basically, some rows on the DB duplicated (along with the primary key). Before I keep going, these are the errors addressed in this post:

```
ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 393410960 from before xid cutoff 393413059 needs to be frozen
```

OR

```
ERROR:  failed to find parent tuple for heap-only tuple at (3,8) in table "your_table"
```

Obviously, the `xmin` value of `393410960`, the cut-off value of `393413059` and the `ctid` value of `(3,8)` could be different in your case.

---

**How I get these errors:**

If you want to get these errors (and you have this problem) this is how you could find them:

```
your_db=# VACUUM FULL your_table;
ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 393410960 from before xid cutoff 393413059 needs to be frozen
```

And to get the second error:

```
your_db=# REINDEX TABLE your_table;
ERROR:  failed to find parent tuple for heap-only tuple at (3,8) in table "your_table"
```

---

DON'T PANIC! The solution to this is given below :)

Answer (score 2):

Before you read this, please note **I take no responsibility for data loss or corruption or any problems this causes!**

I'd suggest you back up everything! But don't do `pgdump`, do a full filesystem backup. Use `rsync` and put it somewhere else.

There also may be other solutions out there, so don't do this one first before doing more research. I can state, however, that this did work for me.

---

So in order to fix this, I followed the advice given in the post at:

http://www.postgresql-archive.org/BUG-10189-Limit-in-9-3-4-no-longer-works-when-ordering-using-a-composite-multi-type-index-td5802079.html

Basically, what I did was the following:

```
your_db=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
your_db=# DELETE FROM your_table WHERE ctid='(3,8)';
DELETE 1
your_db=# END;
COMMIT
your_db=# VACUUM FULL your_table;
VACUUM
your_db=# REINDEX TABLE your_table;
REINDEX
```

Only the lines that start with `your_db=#` are ones that I wrote. So what you can see there is that I deleted the offending row and then ran a reindex. If that fails, you delete the next offending row and reindex until it succeeds.

Hope this helps.